# MP4 video runs slow in videojs player in Firefox and IE but not Chrome

Tags: video, mp4, webm

Anyone know why that would be? I've googled but no one seems to have had the same problem.
The FF version is 30.0 for Windows.  The video (24 fps, 2 minutes) plays but after 10 seconds it is a few seconds behind the audio. The same video file in webm format runs perfectly. Just noticed the MP4 also runs slow in IE 11. Both formats run on time in Chrome 36 on PC and the MP4 is fine in Chrome and Safari on iPad.

Comment: Hmmm... I did those MP4s by exporting them from MOV originals using Handbrake. On a hunch, I re-exported one of the MOVs to MP4 using MPEG Streamclip. Result - the sync problem is with the Handbrake files. Basically, the audio starts earlier than the video.  In Firefox and IE, the Streamclip MP4 runs on time.

Comment: 19 August. I was exporting MOVs from Handbrake as mp4s using Normal preset plus "variable framerate". With "variable", the mp4 is 2 minutes long. With "constant framerate", it's 1m 58s. In FF, "constant" gives perfect synch, but the animation is jerky. Looks like those extra 2 seconds with "variable" are added at the very beginning - the video starts lagging immediately behind the audio. (Bet no one else in the universe has had this problem.)